# Spring RestTemplate POST Query with Headers and Body

Tags: spring, rest

I need to consume the given API definition, But I am not able to find a function call that takes both headers and request body at [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html). Please suggest which function of RestTemplate to use here.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createObject", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<CreateObjectOutput> createObject(
        @RequestBody CreateObjectInput req) 
{
    CreateObjectOutput out = new CreateObjectOutput();
    ///// Some Code
    return new ResponseEntity<CreateObjectOutput>(out, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: I have access to API definition as well. Please suggest if the definition itself has some issue.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
CreateObjectInput payload = new CreateObjectInput();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

HttpEntity<CreateObjectOutput> requestEntity = 
     new HttpEntity<>(payload, headers);
CreateObjectOutput response = 
   template.exchange("url", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, 
              CreateObjectOutput.class);
```

Comment: HttpEntity class was the answer ofcourse. I even check RequestEntity Class and the RequestBuilder was particularly interesting :)

Comment: Most succinct and best answer in a sea of confusion.  This answered both my input and output questions.  I did not know you could create a templated version of HttpEntity.

Comment: I think that Inside HttpEntity class we have to specify the CreateObjectInput and not the CreateObjectOutput

Answer (score 6):

```
//Inject you rest template
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTmplt;
```

Then use it inside your method.

```
HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();

//You can use more methods of HttpHeaders to set additional information
header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

Map<String, String> bodyParamMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

//Set your request body params
bodyParamMap.put("key1", "value1");
bodyParamMap.put("key2", "value2");
bodyParamMap.put("key3", "value3");
```

You can convert your request body to JSON formatted string using
writeValueAsString() method of ObjectMapper.

```
String reqBodyData = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(bodyParamMap);

HttpEntity<String> requestEnty = new HttpEntity<>(reqBodyData, header);
```

postForEntity() for POST method
getForEntity() for GET method

```
ResponseEntity<Object> result = restTmplt.postForEntity(reqUrl, requestEnty, Object.class);
        return result;
```

ObjectMapper is Jackson dependency
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.ObjectMapper()

In place of ResponseEntity Object class it can be your own class too based on response you are expecting.

For example:

```
ResponseEntity<Demo> result = restTmplt.postForEntity(reqUrl, requestEnty, Demo.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

****Api header and body parameter added for a post req:** **

> You have to provide apiKey and apiUrl value to use this POST req. Thanks in advance

```
public JSONObject sendRequestToPorichoyUsingRest(String nid,String dob){
    JSONObject jsonObject=null;
    try {
        // create headers
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        // set `content-type` header
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        // set `accept` header
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.set("x-api-key",apiKey);
        // request body parameters
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("national_id",nid);
        map.put("dob",dob);
        // build the request
        HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
        // send POST request
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(apiUrl, entity, String.class);

        // check response
        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            System.out.println("Request Successful");
            System.out.println(response.getBody());
            JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
            jsonObject=(JSONObject) parser.parse(response.getBody());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Request Failed");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        LOGGER.error("Something went wrong when getting data from porichoy "+e);
    }

    return jsonObject;
}
```